# How to get the correct Image height and width

Tags: c#, image, height, size, width

I am trying to calculate the size of a `Rectangle` using the `Height` and `Width` of an image in my project.  The image (icon) is 20px W and 16px H. When I load it in from a `ImageList` and look at the image size, it shows that it is 16px X 16px.

I assume that there is some compression that is being applied to the image, but I am not very experienced in this area.  I just need to get the correct, dimensions.
Is there any way?

NOTE:  I am not loading the file from disk... it is in my project.

This, simply, is what I am doing:

```
var tabPage = _tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];

var image = _tabControlImageList.Images[tabPage.ImageIndex];
var imageHW = Math.Max(image.Height, image.Width);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and must declare a `ImageSize` you want to have, before you load the `Images` into the `ImageList`:

```
_tabControlImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 16);
```

Afterwards all your `Images` inside the `ImageList` will have following size: `20x16px`.

Comment: Yes, and he should also change the `ColorDepth` to a nicer quality..! And it should be mentioned that __all__ images in the `ImageList` will have the __same__ `Size` and `ColorDepth`..

Comment: Ah, got it.  Then one more follow up.

Comment: Is there any way to have one image that is a different size.  All that I have are 20x20 except the one.  If not, I can just recreate the image with padding, just thought I would ask.

Comment: no this won't work, and also this is not the suppose a `ImageList` is for... yes, you have to recreate the Image with padding to get it working for you.